# ASP.NET MVC3 Complex Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a the following default route set up and it works fine:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Here is an example of successful route for me: "/PositionDetail/Candidates/2"

This is all fine and dandy, but the issue I have is that I want to set up a route that goes deeper. i.e. **"/PositionDetail/Candidates/2/GetMoreCandidates"** and **"/PositionDetail/Candidates/2/Resume/3"** where the Resume would be another action that I want to perform, and 3 would be ID. Note: Each of these route will load a new page, and not some partial view.

How do I set something up like this, and what would the 'PositionDetail' Controller Look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, for second task it may be as follows:

```
public ActionResult Resume(int CandidateID, int ResumeID)
{

return View();
}
```

In your Routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Resume", // Route name
                "{controller}/Candidates/{CandidateID}/{action}/{ResumeID}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "PositionDetail", action = "Resume", CandidateID = UrlParameter.Optional, ResumeID= UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

For fist task - the same logic